# Pass commands to interactive shell in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, stdout, stdin

I have an ELF file (executable file), which after execution gives you a shell, something like this:

```
$./execute-me <- executing this file
# whoami <- it has provided me a shell(popped a shell) and I ran `whoami` command
root <- output of `whoami` command
#
```

I want to call this file *execute-me* into a python program and provide a command that it should run, like after calling this file I want to pass commands to it:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess
subprocess.run('execute-me') <- executing ELF file
subprocess.take.input<- here I want to pass `whoami` command
```

Comment: python shouldn't be the executable but `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do, and what `execute-me` does. However, to execute binaries (or scripts) in Python, you can use the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module from the standard library. You can pass arbitrary input to subprocesses, including the content of the program file you are running.

Comment: Actually, I don't know how to do `subprocess`. Let me try updating it.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to kind of "remote control" that particular shell, by feeding commands into it and receiving the responses to your commands. Did you consider using [pexpect](https://pypi.org/project/pexpect/) for this task? How is that shell communicated with the world (i.e. via stdin/stdout, or directly talking to a terminal device?).